# Adding toolbar and floatingactionbutton using drag and drop

Tags: android, widget

I am learning Android right now and I have really simple question.
Recently I came acroos 2 widgets: toolbar and floatingactionbutton. But they are not displayed in Android Studio's Palette for draging and droping. Can I add them somehow there? Or do I have to always create them using code?